# Magento - Sorting product collection

Tags: magento, sorting, collections, filter, product

I have a product collection which needs to be filtered. For this I have overridden the 'Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List' and have the following code:

```
$collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('language', array('in' => 
array('B','C','E')));
$collection->addAttributeToSort('language', 'DESC');

return $this->_productCollection;
```

On the front end this sorts in the form of E,C,B

If I set the attribute to sort to 'ASC' the sort is in the form of B,C,E

What I need however is to specify the order to E,B,C

Is there any way this can be done?

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE

I have tried fin_Set and looked at the link you sent. I tried the code:

```
 $collection = parent::_getProductCollection();
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('language', 
 array('finset'=>'E','C,E,B'));

return $this->_productCollection;
```

However this only shows products set as 'E' I have also tried the code you provided but I receive an empty product list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
parent::_getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('language', array('finset'=>'B,C,E'));

return $this->_productCollection;
```

`finset` maps to MySQL's [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Comment: Please my update on the question. I have tried your code and alterations based of the link you gave.

Comment: I didn't said `array('finset'=>'E','C,E,B')`, but `array('finset'=>'C,E,B'))`. I don't think it even works the way you've written.